# USSD command sender to 3G Modem

Tags: usb-modem, 3g, ussd

Does anybody know any software with GUI interface for sending USSD commands to 3G Modems?

I have found only [this](https://honk.sigxcpu.org/piki/projects/ppm/) but it uses xml file and you need to store commands in xml file before sending.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is Modem Manager. It can be installed by

```
sudo apt-get install modem-manager-gui
```

Comment: I am not able to send USSD codes properly using Modem Manager GUI @Pilot6 . Please see this "[Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/643271/how-to-send-ussd-codes-using-modem-manager-gui)" for further details and help me if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to check your balance or top up on a SIM-Card, there is the [Prepaid-manager-applet](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/prepaid-manager-applet/). It has a nice graphical interface and is in the official repositories: [image: Screenshot of the Prepaid-Manager-Applet]

If your provider is not already listed, you can add the USSD-number to '/usr/share/mobile-broadband-provider-info/serviceproviders.xml'. Find the section of your country and provider and add

```
    <balance-check>
        <ussd>*102#</ussd>
    </balance-check>
```

whereas `*102#` has to be replaced by your providers USSD-code.
If you also want to top up your phone with this applet, you also need to add

```
    <balance-top-up>
        <ussd replacement="CODE">*130*CODE#</ussd>
    </balance-top-up>
```

And secondly you can also send USSD commands via [gammu](http://wammu.eu/gammu/). Install [wammu](http://wammu.eu/gammu/) for a graphical interface. The configuration of gammu will be more complicated but it offers a lot more functionality -- you can send USSD commands of any kind, not just for balance-check.